# How to open specific page from OneSignal notification in Flutter with go_router?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, onesignal, flutter-go-router, gorouter

I'm using the go_router package for routing in Flutter App. And we are using OneSignal for notifications. I'm using this handler when the user tried to open a notification

```
OneSignal.shared.setNotificationOpenedHandler(
    (OSNotificationOpenedResult result) {
  OSNotification payload = result.notification;

  print('"OneSignal: notification opened: ${result}');
});
```

I tried solutions from other answers but it's not working. My first question was, where to put this code in the app, Do I need to put it inside **main function** or here in Material App?

```
MaterialApp.router(
    routerConfig: router,        
  ),
```

And how to open a specific page in this case? Do I need to implement some listener inside go_router and listen to some state and that state will be updated when the user clicks on the notification, is that solution?

Answer (score 0):

My main looks like:

```
 class MyApp extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
      const MyApp({super.key});
    
      @override
      ConsumerState<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends ConsumerState<MyApp> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        print('User: ${ref.watch(userDataProvider)?.data?.email}');
        print(
            'Role: ${Roles.roleChecker(ref.read(userDataProvider)?.data?.roles) ?? ""}');
        print(
            'Token: ${ref.watch(sharedPreferencesProvider)?.getString(SharedPreferencesNames.token.name)}');
        print('User ID: ${ref.watch(userDataProvider)?.data?.id}');
        print(
            "device id: ${ref.watch(sharedPreferencesProvider)?.getString(SharedPreferencesNames.deviceid.name)}");
    
        var router = ref.read(routing);
//CALLS HERE....
        OneSignalWapper.handleClickNotification(ref, router);
        return MaterialApp.router(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          themeMode: ref.watch(themeProvider),
          theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
          darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          routeInformationParser: router.routeInformationParser,
          routerDelegate: router.routerDelegate,
          routeInformationProvider: router.routeInformationProvider,
        );
      }
    }
```

Then I created a custom OneSignal wrapper file like this:

```
class OneSignalWapper {
  static void handleClickNotification(WidgetRef ref, GoRouter router) {
    OneSignal.shared.setNotificationOpenedHandler(
        (OSNotificationOpenedResult result) async {
      print("object");
      // OSNotification payload = result.notification;
      switch (ref.watch(userDataProvider)?.data?.accountType) {
        case Roles.user:
          router.pushNamed(RouteNames.userPushNotifications.name);
          break;
        case Roles.admin:
          router.pushNamed(RouteNames.adminHomePage.name);
          break;
        case Roles.assistant:
          router.pushNamed(RouteNames.assistantHomePage.name);
          break;
        default:
          router.pushNamed(RouteNames.login.name);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For onesingle package version 5.0.4

```
  OneSignal.Notifications.addClickListener((event) {
      handleNotification(event.notification.additionalData);
    });

  void push(Widget child) {
    Navigator.push(
      widget.navigatorKey.currentState!.context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          return child;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

void handleNotification(var message) {
debugPrint("message data is: ${message['type']}");

```
final data = message;
final type = data['type'];
final id = data['id'];

if (type == 'order') {
  push(OrderView());
}
```

}